# How to index in Elastic Search a typed object with a GeoShape string GeoJson polygon?

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, geojson, nest

I have a typed class that contains a GeoJson string variable that represents a polygon.
How can I index it in Elastic Search using NEST?
Marking the field with:

```
[ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.GeoShape)]
public string Polygon { get; set; }
```

and having it in the `CreateIndex` as

```
 .GeoShape(s => s
    .Name(m => m.Polygon)
    .Tree(GeoTree.Geohash)
    .TreeLevels(2)
    .DistanceErrorPercentage(0.025))
```

Gives this error:

> failed to parse [polygon]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Shape must be an object consisting of type and coordinates"

Since I have the GeJSon as the input and the GeoShape has the coordinates as Geo JSON, how can I map this data? I could deserialize the input and populate the ES structure, but it seems like a too complicated, error prone approach.

Thank you,

Monica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [a blog post about working with Geospatial queries with Elasticsearch and NEST](http://forloop.co.uk/blog/geospatial-search-with-elasticsearch-and-nest#sthash.hqfcsP9L.dpbs).

A good way of handling fields that you want to persist as `geo_shape` types and work with them easily within your application is to use [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) that contains,amongst many other useful things, a serializer to convert `IGeometry` types (e.g. Polygon, LineString, MultiPolygon) in code into GeoJSON, the format that the `geo_shape` type supports. The serializer can then be registered with the NEST client so that model properties of type `IGeometry` are handled correctly.

[I have an example of doing this up on BitBucket.](https://bitbucket.org/forloop/elasticsearchexamples/src)

Comment: Thank you Russ! You saved me a lot of time. The conversion worked great!

Comment: @Monica No problem, happy to help :)

Comment: Hi, @RussCam! 
Where can i find, please, an updated working example with searializer modified to accept Geometry from NTS? Other than your old example with SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier ? Thank you!

Comment: @RussCam How can i add the Polygon as GeoShape? I tried two scenarios: 
1. `JsonNetSerializer.Default` - object deserialized with JSON is ingested but property in ElasticSearch is not of type GeoShape, but instead, it's an object with two properties (type and coordinates)
2. CustomSerializer in which added NTS `GeometryConverter`), tried to ingest `IFeature.Geometry` but getting error: `Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'coordinateValue' with type 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate'. Path 'GeoField.coordinate'`

Comment: @FlorinVîrdol Here's an example with NEST 7.x and NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON 2.0.4: https://gist.github.com/russcam/5c40e5c6fb95b9afd9242df675fce428

Comment: Thank you very much, @RussCam! 
I tried running the provided example, but, getting this error: `InnerException = {"Self referencing loop detected for property 'coordinateValue' with type 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate'. Path 'geometry.coordinate'."}` What i'm missing?! I'm using `NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry` and `NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Coordinate`

Comment: @FlorinVîrdol what versions of NEST and NetTopologySuite are you using?

Comment: @RussCam NEST 7.10.1 NetTopologySuite 2.1.0 and NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON 2.0.4
I get the same `Self referencing loop detected...` error even when i'm using a `featureCollection[0].Geometry` from `var featureCollection = new GeoJsonReader().Read<FeatureCollection>(jsonData)` instead of your mock polygon object.

Comment: @FlorinVîrdol For `FeatureCollection` you need to also add `FeatureCollectionConverter` to the list of converters. You may want to add all of the converters from NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJson see here: https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/tree/develop/src/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/Converters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227201/discussion-between-florin-virdol-and-russ-cam).

Answer (score 1):

Russ Cam's solution looks nice. But it's overkill if you need just get shapes from a file and import it into ElasticSearch. To make it work you just need to deserialize your json to an object.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
```

So if model has Polygon as `object` instead of `string`, it will work.

```
[ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.GeoShape)]
public object Polygon { get; set; }
```